# Safari Float Left Issue with Broken Links

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, css-float

I'm pulling data directly through a javascript function and some of the data is broken but both firefox and google chrome format the data into a table like format as I intended for it to be...

I'm not the best with explaining so I made this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4qQAm/

For some reason Safari is spacing them incorrectly and it's looking very sloppy... any idea why or how to fix this?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I have taking a look at the code please change at your css,
change "myUserPosts" this ID at your Css with "lastestposts" ID and change the width as you want to Enjoy and have a nice day.

Comment: just to make sure you are doing it right i have changed your code and upload it take a look.... http://pastebin.com/VAsLthjd Copy this code and try it look at the changed i did what i told you to do with the div ID and i added some </div> that was Missing and i defined the with to 100% but you can change it but it will Reduce the space of your floating items, Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is expecting jQuery to be present. There's jQuery code on your img tags to hide the element in the case of an error. The images are using the [onerror](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp) event to hide the element if an image doesn't load correctly.

```
<a href="http://hiero-glyph.com/post/23671192570/you-are-so-sexy" class="postLink">
  <img src="" onerror="$(this).hide();" class="photo" style="display: none; ">
</a>
```

The simplest solution would be to ensure that jQuery is present.

Comment: yea jquery is definitely present... I tried using masonry but it didn't help Safari's case.

Comment: Hrm, on jsfiddle all I did was switch jQuery on and the layout cleaned up. http://jsfiddle.net/4qQAm/1/